# Array push and jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I've this piece of code. I need it to create a set of input elements and then remove them all:

```
function inputReset(){  
    var td = new Array();
    $('#aaa').find('input').each(function(){
        td.push($(this).parent());
        alert(td[0][0].nodeName);
    });
    alert(td[0][0]);
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        var value = td[i].children('input').val();  
        alert(td[0][0].nodeName);
    }
    try{
        td.children('input').remove();
        td.text(value);
    }catch(err){
        //alert($('#aaa').html())
    }
}

$('td[text="editable"]').click(function(){          
        $('td[text="editable"]').unbind('click');           
        inputReset();
        $('td[text="editable"]').each(function(index){
            if(index < 2){
                var value = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" name="i'+index+'" value="'+value+'" style="width: 100%" />');
            }
        });
        $(document).keyup(function(e){
            var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
            if(keyCode == 27)
                inputReset();

        });
    }
);
```

I can't understand why the first alert shows me the 0 element I pushed into it, while the second tell me "**tdArray[0] is undefined**".

Any ideas?

Thx a lot

Comment: this specific index being overwritten?

Comment: working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/KXbyC/5/, unless you implemented it some other way, the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Niklas Curiously the input tags i'm looking for are added by jquery in a previous step. But if this was the mess, nor the first nor the second alert should give me something, don't you think?

Comment: @Nemus please share all of the relevant code so we can better try to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me... I get two alerts with div:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/E2Eez/